# How do I Prove that $M:=A(X_u)\cdot X_v=A(X_v)\cdot X_u$?

Tags: differential-geometry

How can we show that

$$M:=A(X_u)\cdot  X_v=A(X_v)\cdot X_u\ ,$$

where $A$ is the shape operator and $X_u$, $X_v$ are the coordinate vectors?

Comment: Please clarify what is sp, and "shape operator of x sub v dot x sub u". I guess I understand the others....

Comment: yes it is the shape operator

Comment: I edited the question. Actually I am not quite sure what your questions are. What do you want to know about the guassian curvature $K$? You can also edit your question if you feel like to.

Comment: there is nothing for the gaussian curvature. I just want to prove why M is symmetric and x sub u and x sub v can be switched

Comment: pp 211-212 Barret O'Neill , " Elementary Differential Geometry" ? Follow the examples in the pages that follow, doing the computation gives you a feel for the concepts.

Comment: yes, more specifically pg 225 for M

Comment: So, l,m,n make up the Second Fundamental Form , along with E,F,G ( the first fundamental form we get an expression for the Gaussian curvature.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form   ,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form

Comment: I'm just having trouble making sense of the proof for corollary 4.1

Comment: I think it will turn out that you don't use these to compute the Gaussian curvature , it's a difficult bump in the road, hang in there .

Comment: ya I just don't get how $x_u$ and $x_v$ can be switched

Comment: Can you verify it with an example? I mean a surface that is computed, not for us. Just off the top of my head , mixed partials aren't dependent on the order they are taken in.

Comment: $S(x_u) * x_v=U*x_{vu}=U*x_{uv}=S(x_u)*x_v$

Comment: " Since order of partial differentiation is immaterial, X_u_v = X_v_u which gives both the covariant derivative of x_u in the x_v direction, and x_v in the x_u direction." ( I would use this statement as justification for M having two expressions.